# How to parse identically named XML elements as Array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, xml-parsing, savon

I'm consuming a SOAP service in Ruby using Savon which returns a response with identically named elements as single element instead of an Array. How do i retrieve it as Array?

```

```
<ProjectListResult>
    <List>
        <Projects>
            <Project>
                <Name>AAA</Name>
                <Id>p101</Id>
            </Project>
            <Project>
                <Name>BBB</Name>
                <Id>p102</Id>
            </Project>
            <Project>
                <Name>CCC</Name>
                <Id>p103</Id>
            </Project>
        </Projects>
    </List>
</ProjectListResult>
```

```

Comment: Which XML parser do you use? What's your (possibly non-functional) attempt at solving this yourself?

Comment: Savon is an XML parser. http://savonrb.com/.

Could you try converting the hash to an array? The response should have a to_hash method, so what does that return?